# How can I return a column from select query of INSERT....SELECT....RETURNING

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a view `stock_details` as:

```
item INTEGER,
quantity NUMERIC(8,2),
discount NUMERIC(8,2),
taxable NUMERIC(8,2),
tax NUMERIC(8,2),
unique_serial CHARACTER VARYING(50)
.....
```

I also have two tables as:

```
invoice_item(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    item INTEGER,
    quantity NUMERIC(8,2),
    discount NUMERIC(8,2),
    taxable NUMERIC(8,2),
    tax NUMERIC(8,2),
)
```

AND

```
unique_invoice_item(
    invoice_item INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    unique_serial CHARACTER VARYING(50),
    item INTEGER,
    ..............,
    UNIQUE(unique_serial),
    UNIQUE(unique_serial, item),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_item) REFERENCES invoice_item(id)
}
```

I wish to insert the data from a select query on `stock_details` into `invoice_item` and `unique_invoice_item`. I tried to do this using the following query:

```
WITH t AS (
    INSERT INTO invoice_item AS ii (item, quantity, discount, taxable, tax) 
    SELECT s.item, s.quantity, s.discount, s.taxable, s.tax
    FROM stock_details AS s WHERE ..........
    RETURNING ii.id, s.unique_serial
)
INSERT INTO unique_invoice_item 
SELECT t.id, s.unique_serial, ........
FROM t JOIN stock_details AS s ON t.unique_serial = s.unique_serial
```

But this above query is incorrect as it is unable to return the s.unique_serial in the CTE.

Now my question:

Is there any way in which I could return the s.unique_serial column in the CTE?

OR

Is there any other way in which this can be achieved?

**NOTE** There is nothing unique in the `invoice_item` table other than `id` and the `invoice_item`, `unique_serial` and `unique_serial, item` combined are all unique columns in `unique_invoice_item` table. The column `item` in `invoice_item` and the column `item` in table `unique_invoice_item`, both refer to a common foreign table.

Answer (score 0):

I think, as my experience, you can not get `s.unique_serial` directly. I suggest you two ways as below:

1. Add column `unique_serial` in table `invoice_item` and insert its value also, you can get its value at `Returning`
2. Write a function, which is make a loop with each record in your query of `stock_details`. So you have all data you want.

Hopefully my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but from another post it seems you can use something like this

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT s.item, s.quantity, s.discount, s.taxable, s.tax, s.unique_serial
FROM stock_details AS s WHERE ..........),
t AS (
    INSERT INTO invoice_item AS ii (item, quantity, discount, taxable, tax) 
    values(x.item, x.quantity, x.discount, x.taxable, x.tax)
    RETURNING ii.id, s.unique_serial
)
INSERT INTO unique_invoice_item 
SELECT t.id, s.unique_serial, ........
FROM t JOIN stock_details AS s ON x.unique_serial = s.unique_serial
```

Referece - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50693/can-the-returning-clause-return-source-columns-that-are-not-inserted

Comment: The query you have suggested is incorrect. In the CTE t you are not selecting x. So it will not work. The link you have given gives an example of cross join. i.e if My CTE t returned 10 ids and unique serials are 10 the result will be 10*10 hundred rows for table unique_invoice_item causing error while inserting.